# MySQL Stored procedure for updating two tables (2nd with auto increment value from 1st)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to update two tables at the same time in my database. One table is for groups, and the other table is for members of groups:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups (
    group_id                 INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    group_name               VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    group_created            TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS group_members (
    group_mem_user_id        INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    group_mem_group_id       INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    group_mem_role           TINYINT DEFAULT 1,
    group_mem_created        TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT group_mem_pk PRIMARY KEY (group_mem_user_id, group_mem_group_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (group_mem_user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (group_mem_group_id) REFERENCES groups (group_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I want to use a stored procedure to create an entry in `group` and create an entry in `group_members` with the id that was just created for the group.

I know how to do this on the server (I have a java server and I'm using Spring's JdbcTemplate to make calls to the database) but I thought it would be better and more efficient to do this in a stored procedure.

The two individual queries are (im using prepared statements):

```
INSERT INTO groups (group_name) VALUES (?)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO group_members (group_mem_user_id, group_mem_group_id, group_mem_role) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

But I'm not sure how to merge these into one stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_group //
CREATE PROCEDURE create_group(
    #in/out here
)
BEGIN
    #no idea
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Ideally I would like it to return some value describing whether the operation was sucessful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_group //
CREATE PROCEDURE create_group(
    IN create_group_group_name VARCHAR(150),
    IN create_group_user_id INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO groups (group_name) VALUES (create_group_group_name);
        INSERT INTO group_members (group_mem_user_id, group_mem_group_id, group_mem_role) VALUES (create_group_user_id, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2);
    COMMIT;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

In my server I use it like:

```
JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(DB.getDataSource(DB_USER));
int i = jt.update("CALL create_group (?,?)", new Object[] {groupName, userId});
if (i != 1)
    throw new SQLException("Error creating group with name=" + groupName + " for userid=" + userId);
```

`i == 1` if everything went well. Groups will never be created if the user is not added as a member (fixing the problem with my first iteration below).

**OLD**

(non-transactional, causes a problem if the second insert fails then the group is created with no members, it might work in some cases which is why I leave it here but it doesn't work for me)

The following procedure works. It does not return anything and I am just using the fact that the procedure completes without error to assume that it was all ok.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_group //
CREATE PROCEDURE create_group(
    IN create_group_group_name VARCHAR(150),
    IN create_group_user_id INT
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO groups (group_name) VALUES (create_group_group_name);
    INSERT INTO group_members (group_mem_user_id, group_mem_group_id, group_mem_role) VALUES (create_group_user_id, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2);
END //

DELIMITER ;
```